# Pass arguments to Print

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want a class to use a modified 'print' function which only outputs when an internal flag is set:

```
def __quietprint(self, *args):
    if not self.silent:
        print(args)
```

The desired output, when self.silent is False, would be e.g.

```
self.__quietprint("E:", "-1.24")
% E: -1.24  #desired behaviour
```

However, the code as written, unsurprisingly in hindsight, instead outputs the tuple of *args:

```
self.__quietprint("E:", "-1.24")
% ("E:", -1.24)  #actual behaviour
```

How can I achieve the desired effect?

Comment: You need to unpack the args into the call to `print`: `print(*args)`

Comment: That indeed works. I hadn't done it because my syntax checker incorrectly flags it as erroneous. Thanks!

Comment: Make sure your syntax checker is set to Python 3 and not Python 2.